# error while installing linux image and headers

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ sudo apt-get install  linux-image-3.10-3-rpi   
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree         
Reading state information... Done  
linux-image-3.10-3-rpi is already the newest version (3.10.11-1+rpi7).  
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.  
1 not fully installed or removed.  
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.  
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y  
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.130) ...  
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)  
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130) ...  
ln: failed to create hard link '/boot/initrd.img-3.10-3-rpi.dpkg-bak' =>  
 '/boot/initrd.img-3.10-3-rpi': Operation not permitted  
cp: error writing '/boot/initrd.img-3.10-3-rpi.dpkg-bak': No space left on device  
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):  
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1  
Errors were encountered while processing:  
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I checked the disk space with following command:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/modwifi $ df -hT|grep -E "/tmp|/boot"
/dev/mmcblk0p1 vfat       41M   41M  1.5K 100% /boot
```

Then I checked that there is only one image that is installed in my system:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/modwifi $ sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*' | grep ^ii
ii  linux-image-3.10-3-rpi 3.10.11-1+rpi7 armhf        Linux 3.10 for RaspberryPi
```

My SD card is 32GB. Is it not possible to have two kernel image in this space?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in Raspbian kernel packaging. As Raspbian kernel packages are 1-to-1 Debian packages, they also try to use hard and soft links which the boot partition does not support as it is formatted as FAT32.

[Read this answer from GitHub for more clarity](https://github.com/debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst/issues/18)